# Nested Associations and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations, simple-form

Been working through the last part of a tutorial found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOIQDO1yF80

**Using Rails 4.2.6**

The task is to create a review system for a book review app. Just completed the following

Created the review Model and added the associations
    `belongs_to :book
    belongs_to :user`

Created a nested route
`resources :books do
    resources :reviews
  end`

Created the review Controller
`class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :find_book

```
def new
    @review = Review.new
end

def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.book_id = @book_id
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save
        redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end

    def find_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    end
```

end`

Created the partial form `_form.html.erb`

`<%= simple_form_for([@book, @book.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :rating %>
    <%= f.input :comment %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>`

Created a _partial view to display the reviews
`<p><%= review.rating %></p>
<p><%= review.comment %></p>`

Added a link to my review "simple_form" `<%= link_to "Add Review", new_book_review_path(@book) %>` within my book `show.html.erb` file

Added the code to render all the reviews associated with the book within my book `show.html.erb` file
`<%= render @book.reviews %>`

The problem is when I submit a review from the reviews _form.html.erb the book_id is always null so it doesn't display the reviews on the book page. Here is my Console output for the last record entered.

`Review Load (1.0ms)  SELECT`reviews`.* FROM`reviews`ORDER BY`reviews`.`id`DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Review id: 13, rating: 4, comment: "Testing", created_at: "2016-06-18 02:10:23", updated_at: "2016-06-18 02:10:23", user_id: 1, book_id: nil>
irb(main):007:0>`

I receive no error messages. I can manually enter the book_id into the record within the database and they display correctly, however the problem is when I submit the form the book_id inst being passed.

I think the problem is one of two areas.

The reviews `_form.html.erb` line `<%= simple_form_for([@book, @book.reviews.build]) do |f| %>`

**NOTE: When I submit a review the user_id is being stored correctly, and it looks like they are defined in the same place (within the reviews controller)**

```
def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.book_id = @book_id
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save
        redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessor :book_id` in your model by any chance?

Comment: i dont see where @book_id is coming from?

Comment: @Petr - the review.rb has

`class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :book
 belongs_to :user
end`

Comment: @Marv-C - I do a `  before_action :find_book` at the beginning of the reviews_controller.rb which calls a `private` action with the following attributes.

` def find_book
   @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  end`

Comment: You don't need to find book if all you need is book_id which is already passed in params. Also in your before_action, I don't see where @book_id is set

Comment: Hi @Petr Gazarov

Can you help me understand a little bit about "Also in your before_action, I don't see where `@book_id` is set " I thought because I am referencing `@book` in the `find_boo`k it would give me access to all the `@boo`k params? Also, why do I have access to `current_user.id,` but not `book_id`?

Comment: If you want the id of the book, you can say @book.id

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Silly mistake, but took me forever to figure it out.

Within the Create action I had `@review.book_id = @book_id` and should be `@review.book_id = @book.id`

Thanks fellas for helping.